# How to convert Raster to RenderedImage

Tags: java, image, raster

I make a snapshot of screen and thah try to get a part of image, when I try to save  it to file it doesnt work.
Will be happy to get any advice

```
Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
File file = new File("D:\\output.png");
RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(browser.snapshot(null, null), null);
try {
    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) renderedImage.getData(Rect),"png",file);
                 } catch (IOException ex { Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
```

So here what I finally get and it works

```
                     File file = new File("D:\\output.png");
                 BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(browser.snapshot(null,   null), null);
                 try {
                     ImageIO.write(image.getSubimage(100, 100, 50, 50) , "png", file);
                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate "doesn't work". Is the output not what you'd expect or does it throw an exception?

Comment: It didnt give me any output image and not throws an exception. Program just stuck

Comment: *"Will be happy to get any advice"*  1)  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) The stated task can be done in J2SE.  No need for `SwingFXUtils`. 3) *"it doesnt work"*  Maybe it is tired.  Don't be vague at this point.  Copy/paste the error or exception output that results, or describe exactly what happened, as well as what you expected to happen. 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 2):

My guess here would be that you are having trouble casting the `Raster` retrieved from the `.getData()` method into an image. While it should be technically possible to take the raster, convert it into a `WritableRaster` and wrap it in an `RenderedImage`, I would recommend that you basically copied the part of the image instead. 
A quick [SSCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage original = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        // Crop away 10 pixels pixels and only copy 40 * 40 (the width and height of the copy-image)
        BufferedImage copy     = original.getSubimage(10, 10, 50, 50);

        ImageIO.write(copy, "png", new File("Test.png"));
    }

}
```

This works for me, so if you run into further trouble you might consider making sure that the input is properly fetched. If your issue is that the program is "stuck" try out the above code with a dummy image first.

Hope that helps :-)

Edit: I had no idea there was a method called getSubimage, so I replaced the code above with the method. Thanks to Andrew Thompson.

Answer (score 1):

Once the app. has a reference to a `BufferedImage`, simply use the `subImage(Rectangle)` method to create the smaller image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class ScreenSubImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(d));
        BufferedImage sub = image.getSubimage(0, 0, 400, 400);
        File f = new File("SubImage.png");
        ImageIO.write(sub, "png", f);
        final ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(f.toURI().toURL());

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(im));
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```